# Добавление названия профиля браузера в адресную строку

Tags: google-chrome, браузер

Хотел бы добавить название профиля браузера в адресную строку, можно описать как это сделать. Желательно было бы здорово если это могло реализовываться через команду запуска браузера (через командную строку), отдельный его параметр или если это содержится где-то в мете профиля было бы то же интересно знать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]